# jQuery variable to visual studio VB.NET variable?

Tags: jquery, vb.net, variables

How can I get jQuery variable to block of code that is in C# for web development?

Here is what I have for my jQuery now:

```
$("#open-dialog").click(function () {
  var SerialVariable = this.href.split('?ProgramGUID=').pop();
  $("#serial-modal").dialog("open");
  $("#dialog-serial").html(SerialVariable );
});
<div id="serial-modal">
    <p id="dialog-serial"></p>
    <%
          ' Get variable in here
          Request.Form("dialog-serial") ' Doesn't work....
    %>
</div>
```

So.. I have it both as jQuery variable, and also as value in p tag in the form where I want to use it for VB.Net code.

It's web forms.

Comment: AJAX is needed to pass from client to server seamlessly.

Comment: If you are using postbacks then use jQuery to set the value to a hidden form field to access it or use with `runat=server` and access from code that way.

Comment: Is this ASP .NET MVC or Web Forms?